# Matlab: How to create a stand alone application on Linux

Tags: linux, matlab, user-interface, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have a Matlab GUI that uses bash scripts, gnuplot, octave etc. I want to build a standalone application that can run on Linux. I have no idea where to start. Could you help me please?

Edit: I am running Matlab on Linux.

Comment: have you tried to use the same method for generating an `exe` on Linux?

Comment: @Shai. Yes, I did it with deploytool. However when I click .exe files nothing happens.

Comment: Do you install all matlab development libraries?

Comment: @Eddy_Em I don't know. How can I check?

Comment: @newzad, write here what compilation errors occurred when you try to compile matlab binary. P.S. I don't use matlab more than 3 years (since my transition to octave).

Comment: I run deploytool and it creates src and distrib folders with two exe files in each. I tried to run exe file with wine also but nothing happens. During the compiling I didn't have any errors. Maybe deploytool is not the one to create .exe files, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: you cannot cross-compile. If you want to build standalone applications for Linux, you need to be running MATLAB on Linux

Comment: @Amro Yes I am running Matlab on Linux and I want to get a standalone application that works on Linux.

Comment: oh I guess all that talk about `.exe` files is confusing then.. Please edit your question with a step-by-step of what you did to compile the standalone app. btw the documentation is very clear and helpful in this.